# Microservice with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm working in Windows 7. I've Spring CLI v1.5.3.RELEASE installed. In a working directory, using command

spring init --build maven --groupId com.redhat.examples 
--version 1.0 --java-version 1.8 --dependencies web 
--name hola-springboot hola-springboot

I created holo-springboot app. Then navigated to hola-springboot directory,ran
$ mvn spring-boot:run

The application run. Going to http://localhost:8080, I do see Whitelabel error page. Whereafter, I tried to add helloworld fuctionality. That is, in the app, in the packeage com.example, I included the following java class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HolaRestController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hola",
produces = "text/plain")
public String hola() throws UnknownHostException {
String hostname = null;
try {
hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
hostname = "unknown";
}
return "Hola Spring Boot de " + hostname;
}
}
```

Re-built from hola-springboot dircetory,
mvn clean package

I get build failure as at
  https://pastebin.com/77Ru0w52

I'm unable to figure out. Could somebody help?
I'm following the book Microservices for Java Developers by Christian Posta, Chapter 2, available free at developers Redhat.

Comment: You do have all the `import` declarations at the top of the file, right? And a `package` definition?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a dependency on spring boot starter web in your maven pom.xml file https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.3.RELEASE.

Or you are not importing the classes correctly.

Comment: import java.net.*;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;      
     Thanks @Strelok , Patrick. I missed these classes. As also version tag was missing in that dependency in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing http://localhost:8080 but you have defined a mapping in your rest controller "/hola". So you will have to access the url http://localhost:8080/hola as you do not have any default method in your rest controller.

Answer (score 0):

BuildFailure shows that you have not given import statements in you Class. statements missing are the below

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
```

include these and you will be fine.